# Is there a way to get output in second order sections (SOS) format from Scipy's signal.firwin

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, scipy

I am using Scipy's signal.firwin to implement a lowpass filter. Using the rule of thumb formula(s) to estimate the order of the filter, I am getting a very high number. I looked into [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17235/filtfilt-giving-unexpected-results) question, and as it turns out I need to break up the filter into second-order sections.

The linked question mentions how to get output from Butterworth filter in 'sos' format. But I couldn't find how to get output in second-order sections (SOS) format from Scipy's signal.firwin.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The question you're pointing to is addressing an IIR filter. Here, however, you are working with a FIR filter, see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22600/are-sos-structures-better-for-linear-phase-fir-filters)

Comment: @Irreducible I see. Thank you!